# What does the logic board do?

Tags: macbook

I just got my MacBook Pro back from Apple, where I had sent it to fix the fact that it wasn't displaying video.  I thought it was probably the video card (right?) but in fact they said it was the logic board.  I don't know what this is.

Everything now works flawlessly, thankfully, but I'm curious: what is the logic board?  What does it do, and why would it just suddenly break?  What, if anything, can I do to avoid, or at least postpone, its breaking again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the motherboard! Apple calls it the logic board for some reason.
The term came around a while back, when apple still used different hardware to windows machines, and it's sort of stuck.

Comment: It's more logical than having a motherboard! Where's the fatherboard, huh? And I want to keep my PC clean, damn components.